# What does wisdom mean in Islam

Tags: practical-islam, prophet-muhammad

Some people use the term wisdom \ hikmah to explain some apparently unjustifiable actions. So Who has the authority to have a say on whose "wisdom" is correct and demonstrate acts of wisdom?

Also, Does wisdom mean that actions which always work out in the long term?

my take is that wisdom is simply experience learned while doing some actions so as to know what works and what does not. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The terms, then Al Fairuz Abadiy rahimahullah mentions that the Quran Al Karim, there are 6 meanings of Al Hikmah which is as follows [3],

**1. Descriptors of the Qur'an (Al-Hadith)**

The evidence is the word of Allah Ta'ala in Surat al-Baqara,

> And what Allah has revealed to you the Book and Wisdom (the Sunnah).
>   God teaches you by that which is revealed by him that. (Al Baqarah
>   231)

**2. Nubuwah And Minutes of Prophethood**

The evidence of God as revealed when David tells Nabiyullah Alaihissalam,

> Then God gave him (David) of power and wisdom al (prophetic treatise)
>   (Al Baqarah 251)

**3. Understanding in religion**

The evidence is the word of Allah Ta'ala,

> And we gave him wisdom while he was still a child (Maryam 12)

**4. Good Advice**

The evidence is the word of Allah Ta'ala,

> They are the ones to whom We gave the Book, wisdom and prophethood (Al
>   An'am 89)

**5. The Quran contains the Commandments-Prohibition and Prohibition**

The evidence is the word of Allah Ta'ala,

> Call upon the path of your Lord with wisdom and good advice (An-Nahl
>   125)

**6. Can Aqliy proof to the correct Law Syar'i**

The evidence is the word of Allah Ta'ala,

> God gives wisdom to whom He wills (Al Baqarah 269)

Some Opinions Ulama Other

Al-Haafiz Ibn Kathir rahimahullah narrated from Ibn 'Abbas radi anhuma in marfu' that is meant by al wisdom is knowledge about the Quran, verse Nasikh and mansukh, paragraph muhkam and mutasyabih, what is permissible and the forbidden, and examples.

An Nakho'i rahimahullah said Ibrahim al is al fahmu wisdom or understanding.

Comment: +1: But only the first two point corroborate with the verses you mentioned , can you explain the other points as to how the specified verses explain about wisdom. These points merely mention wisdom without explaining what it is. The last para does explain it but do cite it from where have you quoted these sayings

Comment: You can see it [here](http://mahad-ib.blogspot.com/2012/02/kamus-makna-al-hikmah-bijak-menurut-al.html) ... or in [here](http://insistnet.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=259:hikmah&catid=2:hamid-fahmy-zarkasyi) .. in Indonesian